# Joomla 3.3.6 takes infinit time on installing

Tags: mysql, joomla

I'm trying to install Joomla 3.3.6 on a host on linux.
After I create database and set user on it and enter that in installing magic, it gives me information and then appears the "Please wait" screen.
In "Creating tables" the waiting will not finish and Joomla not installed.
But I've installed same version (with same files) on a local host using "XAMPP".
Where is the problem?

Comment: I would guess it's a permissions problem. But that's just a guess. What does the PHP error log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `your_joomla_folder\installation\sql\mysql\Joomla.sql`

Edit :

```
"ENGINE=InnoDB"
```

into :

```
"ENGINE=MyIsam"
```

If it didn't work, try to change `max_execution_time` value to `3000` in `php.ini` and restart your Apache.